# VBA to Javascript

Tags: vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I built a macro in Excel to pull data from a website and I would like to recreate that macro in a Google Spreadsheet - either as a regular spreadsheet or as a type of Google app. The excel file uses VBA and I believe that Google only uses javascript.

Is there a way to get around this? I do not know javascript and would not be able to use what I built in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Docs offers the ability to pull some web info without macros/javascript. You may want to google "Google spreadsheet and xxx" (xxx is what you are trying to pull from the web) and see what you come up with.

Also, you have the ability in gDocs to insert Widgets (which are the javascript bits), but it may not be possible to fully clone your VBA macro in gDocs. They don't provide the flexibility of Excel.

Posting your code may help get more detailed answers.